# Load all user variables into session or just the user's UID?

Tags: php, session, authentication, session-variables

When handling user authentication in PHP with sessions, I see two main options for accessing the user's properties after successfully logging in:

1. Load the user's main properties into the session superglobal
2. Load only the user's UID (username or id # etc) into the session e.g. `$_SESSION['username']`, then fetch the user's main properties on page load and store these in a user object

**Method 1**

- Scope is more easily accessible through the session superglobal

**Method 2**

- You don't have to worry about updating the session variables when the user's data is modified, since you're fetching it on each page

**My questions**

- Am I overlooking other options?
- What is generally the "done" way?
- What about performance? Which method will be quicker under which circumstances?

**Notes**

- When I say the user's "main" properties, I refer to those which will be used on many pages, such as the user's name, access level, email address etc. Obviously you wouldn't load too large an amount of data.
- I am referring to database-stored sessions and not file-based.

Comment: either or, what ever works for the project.

Comment: method 2: what if the user has 2 sessions open and changes his profile?

Comment: With Method2 you will run into the problem that when you update the database, the user-object still has the old values. You then need to worry about making the user a new request. Are you sure you're not running after a Hen and Egg problem here?

Comment: You said you use a database for session storage. So you would always have to access the database to get the UID!?

Comment: method 1 is acceptable but if user has 2 sessions as JvdBerg says, there will be desynchronisation between a user session and the database. method 2 is bad, dangerous, because your user can insert data in your hidden (or such) fields. a better method should be to fetch your user data on your database when needed.

Comment: @JvdBerg & hakre: Isn't that the case for method 1 rather than method 2? If you're only storing the UID in the session, then on each page load it will fetch the correct values?

Comment: Perhaps my language was confusing: by "store these in a user object" I mean only for that page load.

Comment: @edanfalls: that is what I mean, on every request, get the user object filled from the database.

Comment: @hakre: simple fix: add a "reload session data" to the end of the "update user profile" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, only the UID or any other unique identifier (e.g. the username) is stored because all other data could be changed dynamically.
However, it depends on the data and the project itself. Loading e.g. access level, username and email as you said in addition to the UID could be highly efficient if those data is used often and you really care about updating them!
On the other hand, only storing the UID is inefficient because you have to request all data on each page but it's a more secure approach. Anyway, if you need to load further user data on most pages, this approach would be the better one because you have to request data anyway.
Nevertheless, to increase the efficiency of e.g. database request you could use a database cache. If you do so, the efficiency of both ways may be nearly equal.
In short, it really depends on the type of project, needed data and environment which approach is the better and more efficient one.

Please be also aware that if you store user data other than the UID you need to save session IDs too because a user could open more than one session and you need to make sure that he changes the same session if he changes user data!

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I think I need to do some research on how database sessions are accessed to assess the performance difference, and some testing. I think the best approach will be to store only the UID, as it's simpler and more secure as you say, and then move key variables to the session in future if performance becomes an issue.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the project, If user's some information is most accessible then put into session. 
I would do like that:

```
class User{
   private $userName;
   //ohter attrs
   //getters and setters    
}

function login(){
    $user = new User();
    //populate attrs 
    $_Session["user"] = $user
 }
```

DO not put big batch data into session leave it in db, do not put UID either, put some `User` classes object.

Answer (score 1):

If you're concerned about performance then you might want to consider implementing a cache layer (e.g. memcache) and storing your pulled user data in the cache.  The way I usually do it is to just use memcached as the session handler instead of the database.

Comment: I would not say I am so much concerned about performance but just interested. If you store all of the user's properties in the session, and you use, say, 10 of those properties in one page, will that be 10 queries to the database, or will it load the whole lot when you access the first one?

Comment: It depends entirely on how the custom session handler is written.